# How to fix an EDB database error -1022 on an Exchange 2007 (Enterprise Edition) server

Tags: exchange

Unexpectly a database on an Exchange 2007 (Enterprise Edition) was dismounted (aprox 41Gb of size) whe I tried to run the command `eseutil /mh` I get the following error after 0.47 seconds:

> Operation terminated with error -1022

I copied the EDB and transactions logs on a Windows XP with the management tools installed and run the same command and I get the same message.

Can someone guide me to repair and recover the mailboxes? I don’t have a working backup of the database.

Comment: From what I've read, the most common reason for a -1022 error is a database file that was severely damaged or truncated. If this issue occurs, Exchange requests a page number that is larger than the number of pages in the database file, and a -1022 error results. This issue can occur because of issues in the file system or because of improper transaction log replay. Try doing the **Eseutil /p** command to repair the database.